# Remove first n words and take count

Tags: r, regex

I have a *dataframe* with text column, I need to ignore or eliminate first 2 words and take count of string in that column.

```
 b <- data.frame(text = c("hello sunitha what can I do for you?",
                          "hi john what can I do for you?")
```

Expected output in dataframe 'b': how can we remove first 2 words, so that count of 'what can I do for you? = 2

Comment: First 2 or 3??  And how is the count 2?

Comment: after removing first two words, remaining string would be same right, hence when I count them , answer should be 2

Comment: When you remove first 2 you're left with "what can I do for you?", here count is 6 (ie, I don't understand your question)

Comment: could you share code

Comment: If you already know that you've removed two words, why is it necessary to still count them?

Comment: No, I had difficulty in removing them, also I wanted to know how many times this was present in text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to remove the first two words and then `tapply` and count, i.e.

```
i1 <- gsub("^\\w*\\s*\\w*\\s*", "", b$text)
tapply(i1, i1, length)
#what can I do for you? 
#                     2
```

If you need to remove any range of words, we can amend `i1` as follows,

```
i1 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(b$text), ' '), function(i)paste(i[-c(2:4)], collapse = ' '))
tapply(i1, i1, length)
#hello I do for you?    hi I do for you? 
#                  1                   1
```

Comment: Suppose if I want to remove range of words like from second word to nth word (Ex: 2:4), how to go about it? as I have such text as well.

Comment: Well, first of all you should have mentioned this in your original question because now the whole concept needs to be changed

Answer (score 1):

```
 b=data.frame(text=c("hello sunitha what can I do for you?","hi john what can I do for you?"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
b$processed = sapply(b$text, function(x) (strsplit(x," ")[[1]]%>%.[-c(1:2)])%>%paste0(.,collapse=" "))
b$count = sapply(b$processed, function(x) length(strsplit(x," ")[[1]]))
> b
                                  text              processed count
1 hello sunitha what can I do for you? what can I do for you?     6
2       hi john what can I do for you? what can I do for you?     6
```

Are you looking for something like this? watch out for `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` else your texts will be `factor` type and harder to work on.